# How to convert string '00011001010010000000000000000000' to '0x98120000'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, binary

I use MS SQL Server 2008:
I convert `'0x98120000'` to string `'00011001010010000000000000000000'`.
How to convert reverse.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us how you convert from binary to string?

Comment: You might look at this: http://improve.dk/converting-between-base-2-10-and-16-in-t-sql/

Answer (score 0):

```
 declare @t binary(4)
     set @t = 0x98120000 

    -- Out string : '00011001010010000000000000000000'
    Select  REVERSE(REPLICATE('0',8-DATALENGTH(dbo.DecimalToBinary(CONVERT(tinyint,0xFF) & SUBSTRING(@t,1,1))))+dbo.DecimalToBinary(CONVERT(tinyint,0xFF) & SUBSTRING(@t,1,1)))+''+
            REVERSE(REPLICATE('0',8-DATALENGTH(dbo.DecimalToBinary(CONVERT(tinyint,0xFF) & SUBSTRING(@t,2,1))))+dbo.DecimalToBinary(CONVERT(tinyint,0xFF) & SUBSTRING(@t,2,1)))+''+
            REVERSE(REPLICATE('0',8-DATALENGTH(dbo.DecimalToBinary(CONVERT(tinyint,0xFF) & SUBSTRING(@t,3,1))))+dbo.DecimalToBinary(CONVERT(tinyint,0xFF) & SUBSTRING(@t,3,1)))+''+
            REVERSE(REPLICATE('0',8-DATALENGTH(dbo.DecimalToBinary(CONVERT(tinyint,0xFF) & SUBSTRING(@t,4,1))))+dbo.DecimalToBinary(CONVERT(tinyint,0xFF) & SUBSTRING(@t,4,1))) As [String]

    --Out String binary : 0x98120000
    Declare @String varchar(200)
    Set @String='00011001010010000000000000000000'
    Select  Cast([dbo].[BinaryToDecimal](REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@String,1,8))) as binary(1))+
            Cast([dbo].[BinaryToDecimal](REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@String,9,8))) as binary(1))+
            Cast([dbo].[BinaryToDecimal](REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@String,17,8))) as binary(1))+
            Cast([dbo].[BinaryToDecimal](REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@String,25,8))) as binary(1)) as [ChangeBinary]
```

***FUNCTION [dbo].[DecimalToBinary]****

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DecimalToBinary]
(
    @Input bigint 
)
RETURNS varchar(5000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Output varchar(5000) = ''
    WHILE @Input > 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @Output = @Output + CAST((@Input % 2) AS varchar)
        SET @Input = @Input / 2
    END
    RETURN REVERSE(@Output)
END
```

*****FUNCTION [dbo].[BinaryToDecimal]*****

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[BinaryToDecimal]
(
 @Input varchar(255)
)
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @Cnt tinyint = 1
 DECLARE @Len tinyint = LEN(@Input)
 DECLARE @Output bigint = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Input, @Len, 1) AS bigint)
 WHILE(@Cnt < @Len) 
 BEGIN
  SET @Output = @Output + POWER(CAST(SUBSTRING(@Input, @Len - @Cnt, 1) * 2 AS bigint), @Cnt)
  SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
 END
 RETURN @Output 
 END
```